# Как правильно получить "_stock_status" в корзине, используя "WC()->cart->get_cart()"?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В error.log получаю ошибку "Основные методы добавления/обновления/получения мета-данных не следует использовать для внутренних мета-данных, включая «_stock_status». Используйте геттеры и сеттеры."
То есть ругается на `$stock_status = $product->get_meta( '_stock_status', true );` 
Как правильно получить `_stock_status` товаров в корзине, используя `WC()->cart->get_cart()`?

Сам код:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
 $product            = $cart_item['data'];
 $stock_status       = $product->get_meta( '_stock_status', true ); 
 $line_subtotal      = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product->get_stock_status(); // версия 3.0+
$product->stock_status; // версия до 3.0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло